# How to create menu and update icon in Pystray

Tags: python, windows, pystray

I want to use `pystray` module in Python to create a system tray app on Windows.

#### Code

Until now I managed to write this:

```
import pystray
from PIL import Image

image = Image.open("image.gif")
icon = pystray.Icon(name ="SPAM!", icon =image, title ="MOBASuite", menu =None)
icon.run()
```

#### Problem

I had a hard time to find out how this works. Its not clearly explained in a documentation.

When I run the this program, 3 icons are created and I must hover mouse over them to become one icon. Same thing when I close the program.

#### Questions

1. How can I create a menu after right-clicking on the icon?
2. How can I add items to the menu and set default one? (The default-item should be called if I left-click on the icon).
3. How can I update the icon?

Comment: The documentation isn't very good, but I can find an explanation [here](https://github.com/moses-palmer/pystray/blob/master/docs/usage.rst#creating-the-menu) on how to create a menu.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
from pystray import MenuItem as item
import pystray
from PIL import Image

def action():
    pass

image = Image.open("image.jpg")
menu = (item('name', action), item('name', action))
icon = pystray.Icon("name", image, "title", menu)
icon.run()
```

This work for me

I recomend use lambda to call a method

```
item('Call something', lambda :  method())
```