# Why I can't exit code in python?

Tags: python, exit, system-tray, tray

I've tried use `exit()`, `exit(0)`, `sys.exit()`(I've import sys) and `quit()`, but none of them can help me to exit code.

Here is my code when using `exit()`:

```
from pystray import MenuItem as item
import pystray
from PIL import Image


while True:
    def show():
        exit()
    image = Image.open("TrayIcon.jpg")
    menu = (item('exit', show),)
    icon = pystray.Icon("name", image, "title", menu)
    icon.run()
    print('running...')
```

This is the error when using `exit()`

```
An error occurred when calling message handler
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\py3.7\lib\site-packages\pystray\_win32.py", line 402, in _dispatcher
    uMsg, lambda w, l: 0)(wParam, lParam) or 0)
  File "D:\py3.7\lib\site-packages\pystray\_win32.py", line 213, in _on_notify
    descriptors[index - 1](self)
  File "D:\py3.7\lib\site-packages\pystray\_base.py", line 324, in inner
    callback(self)
  File "D:\py3.7\lib\site-packages\pystray\_base.py", line 449, in __call__
    return self._action(icon, self)
  File "D:\py3.7\lib\site-packages\pystray\_base.py", line 544, in wrapper0
    return action()
  File "C:/Users/admin/AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/PyCharmCE2022.1/scratches/scratch.py", line 9, in show
    exit()
  File "D:\py3.7\lib\_sitebuiltins.py", line 26, in __call__
    raise SystemExit(code)
SystemExit: None
```

i aslo have tried to turn

```
from pystray import MenuItem as item
import pystray
from PIL import Image


def show():
    icon.stop()


image = Image.open("TrayIcon.jpg")
menu = (item('exit', show),)
icon = pystray.Icon("name", image, "title", menu)
icon.run()

while True:
    print('running...')
```

At this time, i can't `running...` is not show when the icon is in the tray, i must exit it to show.

Other errors are quiet similar with the error when using `exit()`

Comment: The **purpose of** `exit`, and all its friends, is to raise that exact exception. Normally, it is handled by the Python interpreter itself, but here it has been caught and displayed by `pystray`.

Comment: you have to call your func(`show()`)

Comment: @Ashkan Goleh Pour I've call it in `menu = (item('exit', show),)`

Comment: in the `while` loop your function `show()` gets decleared which contains `exit()` but it is never called any where.

Comment: Never use `exit` or `quit` in your program. To cite the [documentation of `exit` and `quit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html#exit): "They are useful for the interactive interpreter shell and should not be used in programs."

Answer (score 0):

I've given this a test now and you don't need to call **exit()**. Instead, call **icon.stop()**

Also, no need for the infinite loop!

```
from pystray import MenuItem as item
import pystray
from PIL import Image

def show():
    icon.stop()
    
image = Image.open("TrayIcon.jpg")
menu = (item('exit', show),)
icon = pystray.Icon("name", image, "title", menu)
icon.run()
```

Note: the following link would be useful for you as well

https://github.com/moses-palmer/pystray/issues/17

[Pystray systray icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47095129/pystray-systray-icon)

Comment: Sorry, maybe my question is not clear, i must use `while True` in the program. and when i add `icon.stop()` in `def show()`, it tells me `NameError: name 'icon' is not defined`

Comment: What is your reason behind calling an infinite loop!?

Comment: Because i'm making a programme amd this only a small part of it. In that programme it need to do a lot of things in the loop. That's why i need a loop

Comment: I can't understand your point. Anyway, please edit your question and say exactly what you want to do and why you want your loop each time to create an icon!?

Comment: When I turn these out of loop, the programm will stop as soon as i start it.

Comment: On my side, when I run the program just ends when I press on exit and then the icon gets removed!!

Comment: Well, i'm to output `running...` before i exit the programm in the tray, at this time, i must exit the tray icon, then the things in the `While True:` can be output.

Comment: @DanhuiXu

Do mean you want to print `running...` one time when the exit is pressed?
if so, just put the print it in the show() function!

Comment: Sorry,l mean print `running...` before exit.

Comment: Ok ,just do it before `icon.stop()`!!

Comment: Sorry,I don't understand.Could you said more clearly,Thanks

Comment: @DanhuiXu
I mean put the `print` in the `show()` function before the `stop` statement

Answer (score 0):

To exit the shell and return to the system prompt, type exit() or Ctrl-D.

Comment: Well, I'm not working in a shell I'm working in the IDE and doing a programe.

Comment: use the same code.

Comment: Maybe the question is not clear, In my question  i've said that `exit()` is not working in my code.

Comment: This is a comment! not an answer.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).